# Rails 6 + Bootstrap 5 (webpack/yarn install) - how/where override the Bootstrap "primary" color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-5

In a new Rails 6 project, we've successfully installed Bootstrap 5 via `yarn add`

In the older/simpler days of Rails and Bootstrap we had bootstrap_overrides.scss for overriding colors.

In Rails 6 and Bootstrap 5, where does one override colors?

I thought redefining the $theme-colors "primary" could be done right below the `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` statement in app/javascript/packs.application.scss, but that does not seem to recompile the color (even after stopping/restarting the local development server)

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>


# new app/javascript/packs.application.scss:
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// NOT here, apparently...

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": indigo
);
```

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap has default! flag on the variables, so you need to override those variables before you import bootstrap something like this:

```
// in custom.scss
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": indigo
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then, import custom.scss in your template.

Comment: Of course! Thank you! I was incorrectly thinking in terms of a stylesheet where you put styleB after styleA to override it.